# VB.net web api How to get json variable as a parameter?

Tags: vb.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api built visual basic. i need to send json data from ios device with post method but how can i get one json object as a parameter. Send json and parse it from web api and insert to database. i want to do this way. the function that i wanna help is **PostValue()**

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq


Namespace Controllers

    Public Class TestController
        Inherits ApiController

        Dim Jobject As JObject
        Dim Jarray As New JArray


        ' GET: api/Test
        Public Function GetValues() As IEnumerable(Of String)
            Return New String() {"value1", "value2"}
        End Function

        ' GET: api/Test/5
        Public Function GetValue(ByVal id As Integer) As String
            Return "value"
        End Function

'i need help in this point------------------------------------
        ' POST: api/Test
        Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As String) As JArray


            Jobject = New JObject

            Jobject.Add("a_id", "test")
            Jobject.Add("a_kod", "serkan")
            Jobject.Add("a_adi", "asdasdas")

            Jarray.Add(Jobject)

            Return Jarray


        End Function

        ' PUT: api/Test/5
        Public Sub PutValue(ByVal id As Integer, <FromBody()> ByVal value As JObject)

        End Sub

        ' DELETE: api/Test/5
        Public Sub DeleteValue(ByVal id As Integer)

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<AcceptVerbs, HttpPost, HttpPut>
    Public Function FuncUser(<FromBody()> ByVal jsonParam As Object) As Object

        SyncLock kilit
            Dim Jobject As JObject

            Dim e = Request.Method

            ' THİS İS HOW TO PARSE BODY FROM JSON PARAMETER.
            '----------------------------------
            Dim nesne As JObject = JObject.FromObject(jsonParam)


        End SyncLock

    End Function
```

If u wanna post a json data to a VB.net api and if u dont know how to take many parameters with one parameter you should use this.